# How to save multiple data at once to backend from angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two angular forms where the data has to be sent to the backend, I was able to save one form to my backend, but even though I did the same thing to my other form it does not work. I could not find the error, could maybe someone give me a pointer and tell me what I am missing.

This is my form (just the part which does not work)

```
<form [formGroup]="matrialBuyForm" (ngSubmit)="saveMaterial()">
    <div class="form-row mb-4" formArrayName="buyInformation"
         *ngFor="let buyInformation of buyInformation().controls; let i = index">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm col-12 col-md-6 mb-4" [formGroupName]="i">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="sellerName">Seller Name</span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input"
                   aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
                   formControlName="seller"
                   name="seller"
            >

        </div>
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm col-12 col-md-6 mb-4" [formGroupName]="i">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="materialUnitPrice">Price</span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input"
                   aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm"
                   formControlName="price"
                   name="price">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This form is initialized with button click because I have to be able to save multiple entries in one go

The ts file:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.materialAddForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [''],
      articleNumber: [''],
      materialType: [''],
      quantity: [''],
      buyInformation: this.fb.array([])

    })
    this.matrialBuyForm = this.fb.group({
      seller: [''],
      price: [''],
    })
  }


  buyInformation(): FormArray {
    return this.materialAddForm.get("buyInformation") as FormArray
  }

  saveMaterial() {
    this.sellerService.addSeller({
      name: this.matrialBuyForm.value.seller
    }).subscribe(console.log);
    this.priceService.addPrice({
      amount: this.matrialBuyForm.value.price
    }).subscribe(console.log);
    this.materialService.addMaterial(
      {
        materialName: this.materialAddForm.value.name,
        material_code: this.materialAddForm.value.articleNumber,
        material_type: this.materialAddForm.value.material_type,
        quantity: this.materialAddForm.value.quantity,
      }

    ).subscribe(console.log);
    this.materialAddForm.reset()
    this.matrialBuyForm.reset()


    console.log(this.materialModel)

  }


  newBuyForm() {
    return this.fb.group(({
      seller: [],
      price: [],
    }));
  }

  addSellerInput() {
    this.buyInformation().push(this.newBuyForm())

  }
```

this is method to save price:

```
addPrice(price: PriceModel): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
    return this.http.post<PriceModel>(environment.api_server_url + 'services/moniestamanufactoring/api/prices-add', price, {
      observe: 'response'

    });
  }
```

and this is to save seller:

```
addSeller(seller: SellerModel): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
    return this.http.post<SellerModel>(environment.api_server_url + 'services/moniestamanufactoring/api/material-sellers-add', seller, {
      observe: 'response'

    });
  }
```

This is the ts file. the form which is not saved is materialBuyForm. I am using the addSellerInput method to generate the form itself with each click from new. But I can not even save one information. I could not find my mistake I checked it all over.

The console gets for Price and Name the value of null and I do not know why

Comment: can you also provide the related code from the service(s).

Comment: and add the console.log() please

Comment: I edited my answer with the additional methods. RIght now I can not make post requests because I am working on my backend and kinda broke it haha. But the response was 201, with price and seller being null

Comment: No one? I could still not make it work